# How to set the maximum height of bottomsheetdialog on Android?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I'm using a bottomsheetdialogfragment in android and inside this dialog there is a recyclerview. I don't want this dialog to scroll and cover the whole screen, how can I do that?

**MyBottomSheetDialogFragment.kt**

```
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val windowManager = context?.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager

        val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState) as BottomSheetDialog
        dialog.setOnShowListener {
            val sheet =
                (it as BottomSheetDialog).findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as FrameLayout?
            val behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(sheet!!)
            val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
            windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)

            behavior.peekHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / 2
            behavior.isDraggable = false
        }
        return dialog
    }
```

I tried the solution above, but when I do this, I cannot see all the elements in the recyclerview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxHeight="500dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/add_to_basket_bg_color"
        android:fontFamily="@font/forza_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingVertical="14dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_close_white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/header"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/header" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/variantsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the support of my teammate, we solved the problem. In addition, we added the following code.

```
behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
sheet.layoutParams.height = displayMetrics.heightPixels / 2
```

Comment: Test your app in split screen and in windowed mode.